# (JAVA) Timeout para token randômico

Tags: java, random, token, timeout

Estou gerando um token alfanumérico dessa forma:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
long longToken = Math.abs(secureRandom.nextLong()); 
String random = Long.toString(longToken, 16);
```

Preciso de um mecanismo que defina o tempo de vida desse token, para que ele não seja usado mais de uma vez (Exemplo: Algo no sentido do timeout do JWT). Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?